# Easy way to open the Mail application with an pre-defined message subject and body?

Tags: iphone, url, email

In my app the user generates text content. I want to enable the user to launch the Mail application, which then should contain a specified subject and message body. Like: You write a poem in my app and then want to send it to your new girlfriend. So you tap a mail icon and the Mail app opens, containing already an subject and message body with your poem inside.

Someone said there is a kind of URL mechanism for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MFMailComposeViewController for sending the mail.

```
-(void)OpenMail{
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setSubject:@"my new poem"];
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
}
```

emailBody is string which contains the poem.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple URL Scheme Reference: Mail Links](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MailLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007892-SW1) lists all your options.

Or you use `MFMailComposeViewController`.